# Order map with same keys

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to create a map `Integer` to `String`, and this map order my keys.
so i use :

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> thm = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
thm.put(100, "String 1");
thm.put(11, "String 2");
thm.put(100, "String 3");
```

The problem is when i have two same keys, my `TreeMap` contains just one ! how to create a `TreeMap` that cobntains two same kays ? if `TreeMap` does not resolve my problem what can i do please ?

I read your reply is  `Guava Tree multi-map`  but multiMap does not order my keys

Comment: Do you need two separate keys, or two values for the same key ?

Comment: I hope to can separate !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use [Guava Tree multi-map](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) for this purpose. Map overrides existing key with new key if it exists.

Example:

```
   Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = TreeMultimap.create();      
  // Adding some key/value
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
  myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot")
```

Here is a tutorial on how to use [mutli-map](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html).

Comment: But it's not ordred : when i make :

    ListMultimap<Integer, String> thm = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    thm.put(100, "key 1");
    thm.put(11, "key 2");
    thm.put(3, "key 3");
    System.out.println(thm);
I have 100 --> 11 --> 3

Answer (score 2):

If you need multiple values per key, check out the [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K, V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

In particular (to address your sorting requirement) the implementation [TreeMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) will order keys and values. From the doc:

> Implementation of Multimap whose keys and values are ordered by their
>   natural ordering or by supplied comparators.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using a TreeMap, I suppose you're interested in the natural sorting on keys.

If so, the simplest solution seems to use a `TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>`, to create an `ArrayList<String>` when adding and there is nothing and to add items to the list when it already exists

Answer (score 2):

**java.util.Map** implementing classes don't allow **duplicate keys**. for alternative look for  **Guava Multimap**.

```
map.put("key1", "val1");
 map.put("key1", "val2");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to handle a mapping from keys to multiple values google guava libray [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), it maps keys to values, similar to Map, but in which each key may be associated with multiple values. Implementation of Multimap is ArrayListMultimap, HashMultimap, SetMultimap etc.

```
Multimap<Integer, String> thm = TreeMultimap.create();
thm.put(100, "key 1");
thm.put(11, "key 2");
thm.put(100, "key 3");
```

Comment: But result is not ordred if i make 
But it's not ordred : when i make :

    thm.put(100, "key 1");
    thm.put(11, "key 2");
    thm.put(3, "key 3");

Comment: order in list values or keys ?

Comment: Look at my example ! i have two keys with values 100 !

Answer (score 0):

Without having to rely on external libraries, you can create instead a

```
`Map<Integer,List<String>> thm= new TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>();`
```

To add you have to do

```
  thm.get
```

if it returns null, you put a new ArrayList with one element, if it returns an ArrayList you just append to it

Comment: It is not a solution, i try it :)

Comment: I am using the mobile version, every time I edit it wipes out half of the post.